# Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that every $n$-element subset of $S=\{1,2,\dots,280\}$ contains $5$ pairwise relatively prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, pigeonhole-principle, coprime

A friend gave me the following question to solve-

Let $S=\{1,2,\dots ,280\}$. Find the smallest natural number $n$ such that every $n$-element subset of $S$ contains $5$ pairwise relatively prime numbers.

I am pretty sure, the solution has to do something with using Pigeonhole Principle, but I can't see how to use it. I can see that we need to somehow make a "smart guess" and then use PHP to prove it. But, I can't figure out that guess. Can somebody please help me out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we begin with the real question, we note that $\lfloor\sqrt{280}\rfloor=16$. This means that all composite numbers below $280$ must have one prime factor in the set $\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$. We will use this fact in our answer.

First, we will consider the subset $A$ of $S$ that only contains multiples of $2,3,5$ and $7$. We can use [Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/) to find the cardinality of $A$ as
\begin{align*}
    |A|=&\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{7}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{5}\right\rfloor\\
    &-\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{14}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{6}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{10}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{15}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{21}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{35}\right\rfloor\\
    &+\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{70}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{105}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{42}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{30}\right\rfloor\\
    &-\left\lfloor\tfrac{280}{210}\right\rfloor
\end{align*}
which gives $|A|=216$.

Now, note that, $A$ only has multiples of four prime numbers. So, using Pigeon Hole Principle, we can say that any five elements of $A$ must have at least two multiples of a particular prime, which proves that any $5$ element subset of $A$ is NOT pairwise relatively prime.

This proves that if we want to have an $n$-element subset of $S$ such that any five of them will be relatively prime, then we must have $n>216$.

Now, notice that the cardinality of $A$ is $216$ and $A$ contains exactly $4$ prime numbers (namely, $2,3,5$ and $7$). So, the other $212$ numbers in $A$ (and hence in $S$) are composite.

Let us try to find the other composite numbers in $S$. These must be of the form $11m$ or $13n$ for some $m,n\in \mathbb N$ such that $m,n>10$ (since all multiples till $10$ have already been counted). It is easy to check that the only such composite numbers are  $121,143,169,187,209,221,247,253$. That gives precisely $8$ more composite numbers in $S$. So, $S$ has $220$ composite numbers and $59$ primes (with a $1$ which neither).

Now, consider a subset $X$ of $S$ such that $|X|=217$. We claim that there are five elements in $X$ such that any two of them are pairwise relatively prime. To prove that, let us assume on the contrary that our claim is false. So, any five element subset of $X$ must have two relatively non-prime elements. This forces the number of prime numbers in $X$ to be less than or equal to $4$ since if there are more than four prime numbers, then the set of these primes has all pairwise relatively prime numbers. So, there are at most four primes in $X$ which means that there are at least $213$ composite numbers in $X$. This means that the number of composite numbers outside $X$ (i.e., in $S\backslash X$) is at most $7$.

Now, consider the following eight sets
$$\{2^2,3^2,5^2,7^2,13^2\}\\
\{2\times31,3\times29,5\times23,7\times19,11\times17\}\\
\{2\times47,3\times43,5\times41,7\times37,13\times19\}\\
\{2\times41,3\times37,5\times31,7\times29,11\times23\}\\
\{2\times23,3\times19,5\times17,7\times13,11^2\}\\
\{2\times43,3\times41,5\times37,7\times31,13\times17\}\\
\{2\times37,3\times31,5\times29,7\times23,11\times19\}\\
\{2\times29,3\times23,5\times19,7\times17,11\times13\}$$
Note that the $40$ elements in these $8$ sets are all distinct because of the Unique Factorization Theorem. Also, since there are eight sets, and at most seven composite numbers can be outside $X$, by the Pigeon Hole Principle, at least one of these sets must be in $X$. Also, clearly, in all of the above sets, the elements are mutually co-prime.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems, the question was much more difficult than I expected :(

Comment: @SounokDutta You're welcome! Also, welcome to MSE!

Comment: Did you, instead of $\color{red}S$, mean: _So, there are at most four primes in $\color{red}X$ which means that there are at least $213$ composite numbers in $\color{red}X?$_ Also, wouldn't it be more accurate to say, by the Pigeon Hole Principle, at least $1$ of these sets must be in $X$? One being in $X$ would just mean we took $1$ composite number from $7$ of your sets?

Comment: I definitely agree with your first point, thanks for pointing it out- I'll place an edit. But, I'm not sure whether I understood your second point- do you just want that I use the phrase "*at least* one" instead of "one"?

Comment: I mean, I don't want, I suggested... (=:

Comment: @invisible fine, I'll edit that.